# How to check if tablerate is active in custom shipping method?

Tags: checkout, module, shipping-methods, programmatically, table-rates

I have custom shipping method but I would like to return false when tablerates is appear in Checkout page.

Anyway to check the condition?

Answer (score 0):

I solved by query the tablerate table.